# How to parse this returned XML with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm attempting to parse this XML with nokogirl but I'm having trouble. Any ideas where I'm going wrong? I'd like to get each Dealer and get the values for each of them.

```
doc = Nokogiri::Slop(response.body)
puts doc.content #works, shows the response below
puts doc.DTX_LEAD_ID.content #errors, no method found.
puts doc.NEWCAR_PINGGX_RESPONSE.content #errors, no method found
```

returned XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="www.example.com/">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NEWCAR_PINGGX_RESPONSE xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="www.example.com/SellerMessages">
    <DTX_LEAD_ID>1779853194</DTX_LEAD_ID>
    <SUCCESS>true</SUCCESS>
    <CACHED_RESPONSE>false</CACHED_RESPONSE>
    <PRICE>20</PRICE>
    <DealerList>
        <Dealer>
            <BUYER_ID>0000-2127</BUYER_ID>
            <Reservation_ID>1779853194|0000-2067|520a8037-57c8-497e-be4b-f4ea8dfa6c6f|14187-20</Reservation_ID>
            <Price>20</Price>
            <Name>Randy's Rides</Name>
            <State>MI</State>
            <City>Southfield</City>
            <Street>2001 Town Center</Street>
            <Postalcode>48076</Postalcode>
            <Distance>2.56002068066733</Distance>
            <DealerGroup id="2067" max_post="5" />
            <Contact><Name>John Campbell</Name>
            <Phone>2483521314</Phone>
            </Contact>
        </Dealer>
    </DealerList>
</NEWCAR_PINGGX_RESPONSE></string>
```

Previously I've had a response like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <results>
      <status>accepted</status>
      <id>1724128693</id>
      <purchaseprice>8.0000</purchaseprice>
      <error>false</error>
      <messages>
        <message>coverage available</message>
      </messages>
    </results>
```

Which parses really easily with nokogiri:

```
doc.results.messages.message.content #coverage available
```

I want to do something like:

```
doc.NEWCAR_PINGGX_RESPONSE.DealerList.Dealer.Name.content #returns "Randy's Rides"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking, your data needs to be the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem. Anything beyond that only slows our responses as we filter through the noise. See "[ask]" for more information.

Comment: Don't add "Edit:" or "Update" since we can see if something changed. Instead, combine any added information into the body as if it was always there. Why did you add the edit? Can you not get the solution to work? If it does work then you've made your question confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see what's wrong with a document use the `errors` method. After parsing your XML:

```
doc.errors
# => [#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: xmlns: URI www.example.com/ is not absolute>,
#     #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document>,
#     #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: xmlns: URI www.example.com/SellerMessages is not absolute>]
```

To extract the data I'd use something like this:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(XML)
doc.remove_namespaces!
dealers = doc.search('Dealer').map{ |dealer|
  {
    buyer_id:       dealer.at( 'BUYER_ID'       ).text,
    reservation_id: dealer.at( 'Reservation_ID' ).text,
    name:           dealer.at( 'Name'           ).text
  }
}

dealers
# => [{:buyer_id=>"0000-2127",
#      :reservation_id=>
#       "1779853194|0000-2067|520a8037-57c8-497e-be4b-f4ea8dfa6c6f|14187-20",
#      :name=>"Randy's Rides"},
#     {:buyer_id=>"0000-2127",
#      :reservation_id=>
#       "1779853194|0000-2067|e42fd5c6-0a36-4552-8b6a-ad2decebd0db|14200-10",
#      :name=>"Jarrett's New Car Dealership 01"},
#     {:buyer_id=>"0000-2127",
#      :reservation_id=>
#       "1779853194|0000-2067|3fecb591-3a81-49f9-82b3-1f0d7fb3f7a6|14160-20",
#      :name=>"Campbell's Crazy Cars"},
#     {:buyer_id=>"0000-2127",
#      :reservation_id=>
#       "1779853194|0000-2067|731b09e9-700b-4f41-8cb0-eaf80e861d76|14158-7",
#      :name=>"Demo Dealer 3"}]
```

Of course you'll want to add/remove/change fields being extracted to fit your use-case.

Using `slop` mode has its dangers, as stated by [the Nokogiri documentation](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html#namespaces).

> 1. Don’t use this.
> 2. This may or may not be a backhanded compliment.
> 3. No, really, don’t use this. If you use it, don’t report bugs.
> 4. You’ve been warned!

I've *never* used it as a result. Often we don't want to use `remove_namespaces!` either, but it appears safe in your situation.

Comment: There aren't errors. I just can't figure out how to get at the content with the `doc.content`. if that makes sense?

Comment: There *are* errors, you just want to ignore them. Nokogiri, being friendly like a puppy, will try to fix up the XML so it's usable, but that can go badly, so it's smart to know what it's trying to fix up, hence the `errors` information. Sometimes the errors are pathological and cause the markup to change dramatically after the fix up, and we have to intervene prior to parsing, which again is why it's important to know whether it's valid markup.

Comment: Good to know - when I did the doc.errors it returned `xmlns: URI www.example.com/ is not absolute`, but I assume that's ok?

Comment: Well, it's an error, right? So, no, it's not OK. But, for your use of the XML it becomes a non-issue once namespaces are stripped.